# Alexa - Confirm AMAZON.Number slots

Tags: alexa, aws-iot, aws, nodejs

I have an intent to request a bank account info by it's number. I tried with only one slot of `AMAZON.Number` but if the account number is `***012345`, Alexa understand this as `***012337` (last two digits are wrong). So now I use five slots for this (`numberA`, `numberB`, `numberC`, `numberD` and `numberE`, all those are `AMAZON.Number`) and concat their values (and works great).

**My json model:**

```
{
    "name": "GetAccountInfo_Intent",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "question",
            "type": "TYPE_getRequest"
        },
        {
            "name": "owner",
            "type": "TYPE_owner"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountByNumber",
            "type": "TYPE_accountByNumber"
        },
        {
            "name": "numberA",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
            "name": "numberB",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
            "name": "numberC",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
            "name": "numberD",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
            "name": "numberE",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
    ],
    "samples": [            
        "{owner} {accountByNumber} {numberA} {numberB} {numberC} {numberD} {numberE}",
        "{accountByNumber} {owner} {numberA} {numberB} {numberC} {numberD} {numberE}",
        "{accountByNumber} {numberA} {numberB} {numberC} {numberD} {numberE}",
        "{question} {accountByNumber} {numberA} {numberB} {numberC} {numberD} {numberE}",
        "{question} {owner} {accountByNumber} {numberA} {numberB} {numberC} {numberD} {numberE}",
        "{question} {accountByNumber} {owner} {numberA} {numberB} {numberC} {numberD} {numberE}"
    ]
},
```

I want the conversation with Alexa be something like this:

> **Me:** Get my account with number ***012345.
>
> **Alexa:** Did you request info from account number ***012345?
>
> **Me:** Yes.
>
> **Alexa:** Did you want all info, just IBAN or just bank name?
>
> **Me:** Just bank.
>
> **Alexa:** Your account with the number ***012345 belongs to bank XPTO.
>
> **Me:** Can you repeat?
>
> **Alexa:** Your account with the number ***012345 belongs to bank XPTO.

So I already searched a lot about dialog management (like [this manual](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/mobile-apps/dex/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/guide/Dialog-Management-Guide.pdf?aliId=30213186) and many others links). But how can I request confirmation for multiple slots as one like my case? All must be checked to confirmation? How can I solve this? There is some good example for my case?

**My lambda code:**

```
"GetAccountInfo_Intent": function () 
{  
    var intent = this;
        
    var number1Value = getSlotValue(intent.event.request.intent, "numberA");
    var number2Value = getSlotValue(intent.event.request.intent, "numberB");
    var number3Value = getSlotValue(intent.event.request.intent, "numberC");
    var number4Value = getSlotValue(intent.event.request.intent, "numberD");
    var number5Value = getSlotValue(intent.event.request.intent, "numberE");
        
    var value = number1Value;
    
    if(value == null)
        value = number2Value;
    else if(number2Value != null)
        value += number2Value;
    
    if(value == null)
        value = number3Value;
    else if(number3Value != null)
        value += number3Value;
    
    if(value == null)
        value = number4Value;
    else if(number4Value != null)
        value += number4Value;
    
    if(value == null)
        value = number5Value;
    else if(number5Value != null)
        value += number5Value;
            
    var updatedIntent = this.event.request.intent;
    if (this.event.request.dialogState === 'STARTED') 
    {
          this.response.speak("dialogState STARTED");
          this.emit(':delegate', updatedIntent);
    } 
    else if (this.event.request.dialogState != 'COMPLETED')
    {
        if(value == null)
            this.emit(':elicitSlot', "numberA", "What are the account number you pretend?", "You must provide a account number. What are the account number you pretend?");
        else
            this.emit(':delegate', updatedIntent);
    } 
    else 
    {
        if(this.event.request.intent.confirmationStatus == 'CONFIRMED'){
            this.response.speak("Your account number are " + value + ".");
            this.emit(':responseReady');
        }
        else{
            this.response.speak("Please repeat your account number again.");
            this.emit(':responseReady');
         }
    }
},
```

I also do not understand the logic that the examples show for the lambda function (like in my code). How can I make `this.emit(':elicitSlot')` for all the slots as one?

Testing this on Alexa Developer Console is terrible. I can't debug on this... It is always saying "There was a problem with the requested skill's response".